# Looking for a value in multiple tables

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

I have a table (let's call it ITEMS) and it "binds" number of other tables (let's say: two, SHOES and SHIRTS). What I mean by "bind" - when I insert a new row into one of these two tables, I also insert a row to table ITEMS. New row in table SHOES/SHIRTS has a field that indicates, what ITEM it corresponds to.

```
ITEMS
 id
 21
 22
 23


SHOES
 id  name size item_id
  1   foo   42      21
  2   bar   40      23

SHIRTS
 id   name  size   length item_id
  1    abc   XXL       50      22
```

So let's assume I know value id (for example id=22) of one of ITEMS and I want to fetch all info from database about this item.

I tried `select * from shoes where item_id = 22 union select * from shirts where item_id =22` and to make it work I added in select additional columns, to make sure the number and types are fine.These additional columns had default values and I made my Java application ignore these results and it worked somehow, but I feel this is way too much hardcoded; besides it works for two columns, but there may be way more columns than just these two. This is why I ask you, Stack Overflow - how can I `SELECT * FROM All tables WHERE item_id = 22`?

**Edit.**

I tried JOIN, using JOIN my results looked like ITEMS-JOINED SHOES-JOINED SHIRT and zero rows. LEFT JOIN may be the answer, but I still don't know how to programatically choose when to SELECT `SHIRTS.`*, or `SHOES.*`.

Comment: you need to look for JOIN operator

Comment: You should have a look to the [JOIN](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) operator. Try `SELECT * FROM SHOES JOIN ITEMS ON SHOES.item_id = ITEMS.id` and see the result, you'll understand in no time.

Comment: I tried JOIN, using JOIN my results look like ITEMS-JOINED SHOES-JOINED SHIRT. On the second thought, using LEFT JOIN may be the answer, but I still don't know how to programatically choose when to SELECT SHIRTS.*, or SHOES.*.

Comment: You having problems because your database structure is not normalized. You shouldn't have individual tables for SHOES and SHIRTS. Instead you should have one table with a column of product type. Please google for database normalization.

Comment: @Dimt honestly - how would you like to merge two tables like SHOES and SHIRTS? How many common features do they share? If I had this normalized, I'd have a fixed table, exactly the same I get with `LEFT JOIN`. And how having one table with a column indicating a product type would make picking the right answers different than it is right now? Maybe I'm missing something, but for me there would be exactly the same problem like - ok, I would know that item with id=22 is a shoe, but nothing changes in terms of problem 'How to programatically choose when to `SELECT * FROM SHIRTS.*` or `SHOES.*`'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post is not an answer to your original question but the response to your last comment.

Relational databases are based on the relation between entities. The relations may be one to one, one to many and so on. In your case the *item* is an entity which can have many common attributes shared accross all product types such as price, producer, supplier, quantity, gender etc. *Shoe* in this case is only a *product type* attribute of that entity. This approach will only help you to eliminate the problem you are experiencing now because you don’t need to worry which table to query as there going to be only one `items` table.

Normalization helps to establish relations, so for example if a feature *color* depends only on `itemID` then it goes in the same table. If the *color* is an entity itself, for example an `itemID` describes only a model which is available in different *colors*, then you need to have an individual `colors` table and an intermediary table which will link an `itemID` with different *colors* called composite key. Again you don’t have to worry about which table to choose programmatically because the *colors* for both shoes and shirts will be in the same table. You only need to `LEFT JOIN` that table in case an *shoes* can have a *color* and *shirts* not. As you probably know in this case the `LEFT JOIN` will always return an *item* and if there is no *color* associated with it will return `null` for color column. Same applies to other attributes such as size, style, producer, quantity, etc. Please note that when you have producer then it goes to an individual table as the relation between items and producer is likely to be many to one (many items can have the same producer)  and the ID of that must be referenced in `item` table. Also a producer can have many different contact numbers, and then the contact info goes to individual table as well.

This approach allows you to build a singe query retrieving items of you interest and all required attributes. For example you have a product description page for a shoes category then you do:

```
SELECT      *   
FROM        items AS i
LEFT JOIN   item_colours AS ic ON ic.itemID = i.itemID
LEFT JOIN   colours AS c ON ic.colourID = c.colourID
WHERE       product_type = 'shoes'
```

I hope that my comment above makes more sense now.

Comment: I think I begin to understand. I got rid of all tables like `SHOES` and now I have two tables - `ITEMS` (holding all common features like name, price, producer etc. + item_type) and second, huge one `ADDINFO`, which holds all the other parametres. Now I can fetch the results and knowing item_type I can manage my results and get rid of unnecessary columns in Java. Still, this is not perfect (MASSIVE amount of nulls, fetching and not using columns), but is better than my original approach. Or maybe there is a way to fetch only not null columns? Anyway I feel your answer is the solution.

Comment: I'm glad I could help @spoko however, the post is not an exhaustive answer for your solution. I would recommend you to bring your database scheme to the fully normalized form prior  developing the application that you could benefit of all of the features of relational data model. That will definitely make easier for you to develop rest of your app such as Java logic and will save you future maintanance. You could read some tutorials which are widely available on the google search. From my site I will try to update my answer for valuable links a soon as I have a time.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is a [JOIN](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) but you're messing a bit with tables relationships.

There are two main relationships:

```
ITEMS <-> SHOES
ITEMS <-> SHIRTS
```

In your attempt you are trying to relate two unrelated tables: `SHOES` and `SHIRTS`.

To fetch ALL the data from the three tables you need two JOINs, one per relationship:

```
SELECT * FROM ITEMS
 JOIN SHOES ON SHOES.item_id = ITEMS.id
 JOIN SHIRTS ON SHIRTS.item_id = ITEMS.id
```

To fetch a single value you do the same but with a where clause (and its best a left join to avoid showing `null` values):

```
SELECT * FROM ITEMS
 LEFT JOIN SHOES ON SHOES.item_id = ITEMS.id
 LEFT JOIN SHIRTS ON SHIRTS.item_id = ITEMS.id
 WHERE ITEMS.id = <your_id>
```

The fact that you don't know *how to programmatically choose when to `SELECT SHIRTS.*`, or `SHOES.*`* shows that you need to rethink your data model and rewrite your ITEM table.

Maybe a `SHOE_TYPE <-> SHOE_ITEM` and `SHIRT_TYPE <-> SHIRT_ITEM` ER model is a better approach.

Another approach is to have a `PRODUCT` table, a `PRODUCT_TYPE` table with common product type attributes and a `PRODUCT_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE` table for specific attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The relationships between the 3 tables require an "outer join" if joining all 3 at the same time.

```
SELECT
      items.id
    , coalesce(shoes.name,shirts.name) as name
FROM ITEMS
 LEFT OUTER JOIN SHOES  ON SHOES.item_id = ITEMS.id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN SHIRTS ON SHIRTS.item_id = ITEMS.id
```

Take items.id = 22. This exists only in SHIRTS, not SHOES. So if the joins only allow "exact matches" you cannot "exact match" both SHOES and SHIRTS to 22. an "inner join" requires exact matches.

An "outer join" allows non-matching conditions to exist, so here we definitely need these.

The function COALESCE() returns the first NON-NULL value from the parameters. So if a shoe name is NULL it would return the shirt name, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `Left Join` in this case, as you're not sure which table the item belongs in:

```
Select      H.*, T.*
From        Items   I
Left Join   Shoes   H On I.id = H.item_id
Left Join   Shirts  T On I.Id = T.item_id
Where       I.id = 22
```

Ideally, this would be structured differently, but since item 22 is a shirt, you'll see `Null` values for the `Shoes` table and your data from the `Shirts` table.